# gif animation not animating while making visible = true of PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, picturebox

I am using n picturebox to show a "waiting" gif animation when a user presses a 'log in' button in my C# form.

I added the gif image to the picturebox and set the visibility to false. When the user clicks on the login button I set the visibility of the picturebox  to true. The problem is that the gif animation does not appear if visible property is set to true.

Please advise.

Comment: I quickly set up a test project and this works no problem - can you post some code?

Comment: Are you performing some work (like database access) on the UI thread in addition to changing the PictureBox property?

Comment: No database access. But a call to webservice. But it is done after i set the visibility true. i am having the background of the form set to an image in the design mode.

Is there any other methods to show(render)/hide a gif.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Place a panel over the gif and change the z-order instead of setting the visibility.

Or you could try this

[PictureBox visible property does not work... help please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356629/picturebox-visible-property-does-not-work-help-please)