# PictureBox is not showing up on button click event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using a PictureBox inside a button click event. When the button is clicked I am enabling the PictureBox and I am running a long database call and at the end of the process, I am trying to disable the PictureBox. Inside the PictureBox I have a loading GIF.

But I don't know what's happening. My PictureBox does not show up..

Please suggest how can I fix this. I tried Thread.Sleep(1000), but it didn't work.

```
Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
    Me.PictureBox1.Visible = True
    lblSuccess.Text = Nothing
    UltraNumberOfConveyance.Value = Nothing
    GetData() --Long Running Query
    Me.PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

My GetData Function:

```
Private Function GetData()
        dsCheckPointTimes = GetCheckPointTimesByTerminalID()
        dtDataTable = dsCheckPointTimes.Tables(0)
        chkdtDataTable = dsCheckPointTimes.Tables(1)

        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceName")) Then
            lblConveyanceNameText.Text = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceName").ToString()
        End If

        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("NumberOfConveyance")) Then
            UltraNumberOfConveyance.Value = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("NumberOfConveyance")
        End If

        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("Dock")) Then
            UltratxtChangeLabel1.Value = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("Dock")
        End If

        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("Lines")) Then
            UltratxtChangeLabel2.Value = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("Lines")
        End If

        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("CHECKPOINTTYPE")) Then
            SetFields(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("CHECKPOINTTYPE"))
        End If


        If dtDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            LoadFlow()
        Else
            lblSuccess.Text = "No Records Found! Please check the ordernumber"
            lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PictureBox visible property does not work... help please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356629/picturebox-visible-property-does-not-work-help-please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this:

```
Private WithEvents bgw As New BackgroundWorker

Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
  PictureBox1.Visible = True
  bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
  GetData() --Long Running Query
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
  PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting exception `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblConveyanceNameText' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`. I have update my question with getdata function

Comment: @user1030181 You can't access GUI controls from the DoWork method since that is in a different thread.  Only do the "`long running query" stuff in the DoWork.

Comment: Do you want me to wrap gui controls into different function? and place in completed event

Comment: @user1030181 I'm guessing those first three lines belong in the DoWork method, the rest in the Completed event.

Comment: When I click on retrieve button 2nd time after process is complete the gif does not load

Comment: Does the PictureBox control appear?  Give it a border setting to make sure.

Comment: I am getting this `The process or thread has changed since last step`

Comment: @user1030181 Now you are doing something I can't see.

Comment: @user1030181 I rolled it back to the previous version.  You are asking a new question, so make a new question.  Document it properly for your audience.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026074/getting-the-process-or-thread-has-changed-since-last-step