# Getting the process or thread has changed since last step

Tags: vb.net

Getting this warning. How to fix the process or thread has changed since last step

```
Private WithEvents bgw As New BackgroundWorker




    Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
        Try

            SetFields(Nothing)
            Me.PictureBox1.Visible = True
            lblSuccess.Text = Nothing
            UltraNumberOfConveyance.Value = Nothing
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        Try
            GetData() - Long Running Query
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
        GetData1() - This is to bind UI 
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This usually occurs when there is more than one thread executing the same method and hit that break point at the same time. Its possible you may be clicking on the button a few times which kicks off your backgroud worker and there is collision... Basically the background worker is already running, if so don't run the method again (dont click btnRetrieve)...

Comment: @Zaggler how can i fix this

Comment: Disable the retrieve button when you make your PictureBox visible, enable it again in the Completed event of your worker.

Comment: it does not work when button is click 2nd time . First time it works well

Comment: Is it because the background worker is already running? Put this before calling `GetData()`... `If Not bgw.IsBusy AndAlso Not bgw.CancellationPending  Then GetData() End If`...

Comment: How can reset it to stop and start again when the button is clicked 2nd time

Comment: if i use is not bgw.isbusy it never enters to retrieve latest data to from getdata function

Comment: @Zaggler this did not work

Comment: @user1030181 `this did not work`, can you explain further please? Is this all the code you have that you provided, if not please add other as it may just be the issue.

Comment: Its all code. but i am still getting Process or thread has changed since last step